# Interactive plotting of a subset of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, drop-down-menu, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe of the number of vaccinations per country and per vaccine (here is only an extract, there is about 30 countries in the full dataset).

```
Country    Vaccines  Total vaccinations
Austria      Pfizer               65000
Austria     Moderna               56000
Austria  Astrazenca                9000
    USA      Pfizer              110000
    USA     Moderna               90000
    USA          JJ               46000
  India     Covaxin              312000
  India  Covishield              256000
Germany      Pfizer               36000
Germany     Moderna               22000
Germany     Covaxin                7000
Germany  Astrazenca               14500
```

I would like to generate a bar plot of the number of vaccinations per vaccine for a given country. I would like the plot to be interactive by selecting the country with a drop down menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using a [Jupyter notebook](https://jupyter.org).

Input data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['Austria', 'Austria', 'Austria', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'India', 'India', 'Germany', 'Germany', 'Germany', 'Germany'],
                   'Vaccines':  ['Pfizer', 'Moderna', 'Astrazenca', 'Pfizer', 'Moderna', 'JJ', 'Covaxin', 'Covishield', 'Pfizer', 'Moderna', 'Covaxin', 'Astrazenca'],
                   'Total vaccinations': [ 65000,  56000,   9000, 110000,  90000,  46000, 312000, 256000,        36000,  22000,   7000,  14500],
                  })
```

You can create a function to plot only one country and call it interactively using [ipywidgets](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/):

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

def plot_bars(country):
    df.query('Country == @country').plot.bar(x='Vaccines', y='Total vaccinations')

widgets.interact(plot_bars, country=widgets.Dropdown(value='Austria', options=df.Country.unique()))
```

[image: simple interactive plot]

Here is an alternative version to keep the layout of the graphs identical among graphs:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

df2 = df.pivot(index='Vaccines', columns='Country').fillna(0).astype(int)['Total vaccinations']

def plot_bars(country):
    ax = df2[country].plot.bar()
    ax.set_ylim(ymax=df2.max().max()*1.1)

widgets.interact(plot_bars, country=widgets.Dropdown(value='Austria', options=df.Country.unique()))
```

[image: standardized interactive plot]

Full code:

```
import pandas as pd
import ipywidgets as widgets

df = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['Austria', 'Austria', 'Austria', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'India', 'India', 'Germany', 'Germany', 'Germany', 'Germany'],
                   'Vaccines':  ['Pfizer', 'Moderna', 'Astrazenca', 'Pfizer', 'Moderna', 'JJ', 'Covaxin', 'Covishield', 'Pfizer', 'Moderna', 'Covaxin', 'Astrazenca'],
                   'Total vaccinations': [ 65000,  56000,   9000, 110000,  90000,  46000, 312000, 256000,        36000,  22000,   7000,  14500],
                  })


def plot_bars(country):
    df.query('Country == @country').plot.bar(x='Vaccines', y='Total vaccinations')

widgets.interact(plot_bars, country=widgets.Dropdown(value='Austria', options=df.Country.unique()));
```

Comment: Thanks. This helps. But what if i have many records? Say i have like 40-50 countries and i have around 1000 rows. In that case i will not be able to manually pit all the values in the dataframe right? In that case do i use a gor loop ? Can u please help?

Comment: Have you tested the code? It automatically computes the graphs based on the dropdown value. What exactly do you want to achieve? Can you provide the full dataset?

Comment: Hi I did test the code. It says KeyError. ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3079             try:
-> 3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3081             except KeyError as err:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

Comment: It doesn't look like the full traceback, can you identify the line of code where it fails. Try to remove the `value='Austria', ` part

Comment: Please also give the output of `df.columns`

Comment: Here is the dataset and the question https://stackoverflow.com/q/68416533/16458720

Comment: You did not answer my other questions

Comment: i tried to remove value = Austria but still doesnt work. Csn u let me know wat exactly do u want me to provide

Comment: OK, I realized I had typed `Vaccine` instead of `Vaccines`. Can you try again with my updated dataframe? It works fine for me.

Comment: Where is that change?

Comment: I added a "full code" section at the end of my answer. Can you [make sure you have jupyter widgets installed](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_install.html), create a **new** jupyter python3 notebook and run that full code. It is working as expected for me. If you have any error, please post it here.

Comment: Sure, Thanks! Just a small clarification can i know why we mentioned the countries multiple times in the DataFrame like Austria 3 times, India 2 times etc... Also, what does this this part of the code mean? df.query('Country == @country')

Comment: The `pd.DataFrame(…)` part of the code is to construct an example dataframe based on that of your question. The [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) part allows to filter the data using the `Country` variable. `@country` refers to the `country` variable defined in the `plot_bars` function. Read the [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) documentation for more details.

Comment: okay got it, Thanks! So here i have 12 rows and so we put that in a dataframe. But what if i have 1000 rows and 40 different countries. Can u please help me with a for loop or any other loop which calls that and runs the code,please?